# Asymmetrical encryption for more that two recipients?

Tags: encryption

I want to create an application, where multiple people should be able to communicate with each other securely (think of a decentral group chat) - sounds easy, but here is my problem:

As far as I understood, with asymmetrical encryption you have a public key and a private key. Everyone who wants to send a message to someone has to encrypt it with the public key and the recipient can decrypt it with the private key.

But if there are more than two people that should be able to read all messages, I don´t know how this should work...
Either everyone has the public and the private key - which I think is a bad idea - or everyone has to have everybodys public key and has to send a seperate message to each recipient. 

Also, I want to make a 100% sure, that the one who sends a message really is who he pretends to be. (so nobody is able to "fake" messages)

Is there an encryption algorithm that solves my problem?

Comment: Do you mean _asymmetric_ encryption? Else, please explain in what way the concerned encryption is supposed to be _'asynchronous'_.

Comment: ah, sorry, i mixed these two words - I´ll correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean asymmetric encryption, not asynchronous encryption.

In most cases, we don't actually use an asymmetric cipher to encrypt the content of messages. That's because messages can be large, and asymmetric ciphers are slow in comparison to symmetric ciphers. It's also because of the issue you are contending with here: in a multi-party commmunicaiton, you'd like to be able to just send the message once and have everybody be able to read it.  So the trick is that we combine asymmetric and symmetric techniques into a protocol that solves the problem.

First, we generate a random symmetric key which we can call the "session key". We're going to distribute this session key to all recipients, but we need to do this securely. Here's where we're actually going to use asymmetric encryption. We encrypt the session key once for each recipient using each of their public keys and an asymmetric cipher (such as RSA), and we send the encrypted session key to each recipeint. We can send it to each recipient separately, or we can just build a structure that looks like this:

```
"recip1|recip1EncryptedSessionKey|recip2|recip2EncryptesSessionKey..."
```

and send the whole thing out to all recipients, each of whom will be able to parse it and decrypt their own encrypted copy of the session key. (This is generally how it's done in encrypted email: the list of all encrypted versions of the session key for all recipients is enclosed with the message, and everyone gets the exact same email.)

Once we've securely distributed the session key to all recipients, we can use the session key to encrypt each message just once with a symmetric cipher (such as AES), and send the same encrypted message to all recipients. Since they all have received a copy of the session key, they can all read it and act on it.

Note that as in all things having to do with encryption, it is *crucial* that the session key is really random. Don't just rely on a plain vanilla random number generator for it, and for heavens sake don't roll your own. Make sure that you use a [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

A real chat system would likely be quite a bit more complicated, probably with a mechanism for re-establishing a new session key periodically, and the details of a secure protocol can be quite intricate. I.e., consider how you would protect against a bad-guy stepping in and fooling everyone into using a session key of his choosing! But the basics are as above.

Comment: Is it possible with this algorithm to ensure that only one is able to invite others? As far as I understood, everybody could distribute the decrypted session key.

Comment: You can certainly design the protocol so that only one person can invite others. This, however, does not solve the problem of recipients distributing copies of the decrypted session key, but then again those same recipients could just as easily distribute copies of the decrypted messages so I'm not sure that there's any benefit that can be achieved by preventing them from distributing copies of the session key.

Answer (score 3):

## Controlling the extend of the recipient group

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278203/asymmetrical-encryption-for-more-that-two-recipients?noredirect=1#comment48656096_30278660) to [Richard Schwartz' good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30278660/674064), you ask

> Is it possible with this algorithm to ensure that only one is able to invite others? As far as I understood, everybody could distribute the decrypted session key.

When applying the protocol in a group chat scenario, don't let the term "session key" mislead you. Rather, think of the key for symmetric encryption as a "message key": Each time someone sends a message to the group, they should generate a new random symmetric key, encrypt it with every legit receiver's public key separately and prepend all these cryptograms to the symmetrically encrypted message. This way, each sender decides independently whom they consider a part of the legit recipients group of their own sent messages.

This will give the protocol some more transmission overhead, but this probably won't matter in practice. What could matter is the 'cost' of getting larger amounts of 'good' randomness (entropy) to generate sufficiently unpredictable message keys. So an acceptable optimization might be that, if the group of legit recipients has remained the same, a sender might re-use the session key of their own previously sent message. Never though should they re-purpose a sessions key received from another group member for sending messages of their own.

Off course, even if each sender decides independently whom they consider a legit recipient of their message, you can't keep any legit recipient from compromising messages they received: They can simply forward the messages unencrypted (or encrypted for someone not in the original recipient group) to whomever they want.

## Ensuring authenticity

In an edit to your original question, you added

> Also, I want to make a 100% sure, that the one who sends a message really is who he pretends to be. (so nobody is able to "fake" messages)

Encryption can't do that, but cryptography has another way to make sure that

- the message actually comes from whom claimed to have sent it
- the message hasn't been tampered with since

And the way of ensuring these things is **signatures**, which also are something that public-private-key cryptography enables. Let senders sign their messages with their private key. (Which usually means 'encrypting' a cryptographically secure hash of the message with the private key.) And let receivers verify the signatures (by 'decrypting' the signature with the sender's public key and comparing the result with a hash of the message they computed themselves.)

## Don't roll your own *anything* (except when you should)

Richard's answers advices you to not roll your own (pseudo) random number generator. For anything you plan to use in production, I'd extend this to *anything* encryption:

- Don't invent your own protocols
- Don't invent your own cyphers, signatures or hash functions
- Don't invent your own way of gathering entropy
- Don't roll your own *implementations* of any of the above, even if invented by others

Instead, use well-established cryptography libraries. These are written and reviewed by experts in both cryptographic theory and in the practices of writing secure software. And while even these libraries are often enough found to have (sometimes embarrassing) security issues, nothing you'll come up with yourself will be nearly as secure as them.

Though, for **learning**, implementing any or all of the listed stuff (including pseudo random number generators) is great exercise and helps you understand at least some aspects of the underlying cryptography. And this understanding is important, as it's often difficult enough to correctly and securely *use* the well-established libraries, even when you *do* have some knowledge of the concepts they reveal through their interfaces.

And of course for **innovating** within cryptography, inventing new stuff (and getting it scrutinizingly reviewed by the community of experts in the field) is necessary, too. That new stuff just **shouldn't be used for anything serious *before*** it has passed that review successfully.